# take value in input from js

Tags: javascript, html, input

I need to take a data from a script and then to use it in a form.

So when I click on this span:'

```
<span class="star rate1"></span>
```

The value from the js should go in this post:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rate_product" id="rate_er" />
```

The js script:

```
$(".rate1").click(function() {
    var rate = document.getElementById("rate_er");
    rate = 1;
});
```

But something is not working. The post is empty. Can u guys help me to find out the problem and what I'm doing wrong? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
var rate = document.getElementById("rate_er");
rate = 1;
```

with:

```
$("#rate_er").val(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do `rate = 1`

Your rate variable need to have `.value` appended to it in order for it to actually work.

```
$(".rate1").click(function() {
    var rate = document.getElementById("rate_er").value;
    rate = 1;
});
```

**OR**

```
$(".rate1").click(function() {
    var rate = document.getElementById("rate_er");
    rate.value = 1;
});
```